# python: how to convert an array into a matrix? with error: AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'adjugate'

Tags: python

I want to get the adjugate matrix of a matrix, below is  my code.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix

# firt part
a = Matrix(([1,2,0],[0,1,2],[2,0,1]))
a.adjugate()

#second part
a = np.array([[1,2,0], [0,1,2], [2,0,1]])
a = np.matrix(a)
a = a.adjugate() # here is my problem.
```

After I run this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 12, in <module>
    a = a.adjugate()
AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'adjugate'
```

The first part of my code can get the adjugate matrix.
Why the secondary of my code can not do that?

PS. my original data is an nd array.

Comment: In the first part, `a` is a sympy.Matrix object and in the second part, it's a numpy.matrix object. These objects are not the same and therefore don't have the same attributes. The adjugate matrix is simply the transpose conjugate of a matrix. Since you have a real matrix, just use the tranpose method in numpy for your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can i convert  numpy.matrix object into sympy.Matrix object? So I can get the adjugate matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace your `a = np.matrix(a)` with `a = Matrix(a)`. It will do for you.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix

# firt part
a = Matrix(([1,2,0],[0,1,2],[2,0,1]))
a.adjugate()

#second part
a = np.array([[1,2,0], [0,1,2], [2,0,1]])
a = Matrix(a)
a = a.adjugate() # here is my problem.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can continue my work now. Thanks.

Comment: @Stan, happy to help.